# Run specific program in multiple Windows Server subdirectories

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2008-r2

we have an situation, where it`s needed to run the very same command line program in multiple subdirectories. Our command line program is designed, to start / stop specific process on the server.
Currently, I needed to manually access these folders and run program there, but it is very inconvenient and time consuming. To save up some time, I created primitive cmd, that will do that for me, but there is a potential, that there will be more situation like this with much more then six subfolders.
Our program has different type of command line arguments such as : start, stop, log and so on.

```
echo "Stopping program..."

echo "Stopping p1..."
cd folder1
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..

echo "Stopping p2..."
cd folder2
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..

echo "Stopping p3..."
cd folder3
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..

echo "Stopping p4..."
cd folder4
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..

echo "Stopping p5..."
cd folder5
g stop
echo "done"

cd..

echo "Stopping p6..."
cd folder6 
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..

echo "Stopping p7..."
cd folder7
g stop
echo "done"

cd ..
```

This is what I have came up with, but its very ugly and not very smart. My desired solution would be something like this,

```
D:\rootForMyFolders>helper start *
D:\rootForMyFolders>helper stop *
```

or just specify the name of the folders, where that program will be executed such as :

```
D:\rootForMyFolders>helper start folder1 folder2 folder3
```

I was looking into [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html). Do you have any idea, how to do this securely and reliably ? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess `/D` is more helpful here than `/R` (folders instead of recursive). (not documented, but you can combine `/D /R` (recursive folders) when needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well usually you are better off putting in the full location of a program to run and NOT CDing to the path.

So in 1st example it would look like:

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT/B
)

:Main
  echo "Stopping program..."

  echo "Stopping p1..."
  "D:\rootForMyFolders\folder1\g" stop
  echo "done"

  echo "Stopping p2..."
  "D:\rootForMyFolders\folder2\g" stop
  echo "done"

  REM p3,p4,..etc.
GOTO :EOF
```

Then lets take care of deduplicating some redundancies, but still your manual list just a lot easier:

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_RootFolder=D:\rootForMyFolders"
  SET "_SubFolders="Folder1" "Folder2" "Folder3" "Folder4" "Folder5" "Folder6" "Folder7" "
  SET "_CMD=g"
  SET "_Action=Stop"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT/B
)

:Main
  ECHO.%_Action% programs...

  REM Loop folders runnign the stop command in each:
  FOR %%_ IN ( %_SubFolders% ) DO (
    ECHO.Running %_\%_CMD=% %_Action%...
    "%_RootFolder%\%%_\%_CMD=%" %_Action%
    ECHO.done
  )

  ECHO.Script Completed!
```

Now that we have this into a refactored form where we can easily edit the variables and just loop through them you've already saved a ton of time, as we work iteratively towards a program where you can just specify the ones you want at the CLI.

---

### Reserved for next steps

---

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was approaching to. Thank you very much. With this solution, I can easily extend, how many folders our script will take care of.